# Task never defined: browserSync.reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I upgraded from Gulp 3.x.x to Gulp 4.0.2 and began editing my gulpfile to make it compatible, but I'm stuck on this error I get when I try to run gulp:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: browserSync.reload
```

Here is what I believe is the relevant portion of my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
      browser: 'Chrome'
  })
})

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss and children dirs
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError)) // Passes it through a gulp-sass, log errors to console
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles')) // Outputs it in the css folder
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ // Reloading with Browser Sync
      stream: true
    }));
})

// Watchers
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.series('browserSync.reload'));
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series('browserSync.reload'));
})
```

I'm using node version 11.15.0. Later versions were giving me problems.

Comment: Maybe the reload needs to be in a function?

Comment: Rewrote the relevant piece of code this way but I'm getting the same error...

`.pipe(function(){
    browserSync.reload({ // Reloading with Browser Sync
      stream: true
    })});
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate error is a result of these two lines:

```
gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.series('browserSync.reload'));
gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series('browserSync.reload'));
```

Simply remove the quotes around the `browserSync.reload` calls:

```
gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.series(browserSync.reload));
gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series(browserSync.reload));
```

If those calls were calls to `tasks` then it would be correct to put them into quotes.  But your calls are not to tasks but to your `const browserSync = require('browser-sync)` package.

So it is confusing and will probably lead to errors to use the same identifier - `browserSync` for **both** your package require name and the task name as it appears you did.

As can be seen here:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
      browser: 'Chrome'
  })
})
```

The first use of `browserSync` is as a task name.  The second, in the function body, is a reference to the package name.  And the second is ultimately the one used in your `watch` tasks and would not be quoted there because it is not a task name.  So using `browserSync` both ways is definitely confusing - just pick a different name for one like:

```
gulp.task('bSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({......
```

Also note the `init` added to the above code.  You will need it.